# Is there a better(cleaner) way to write this JS code using ternary operators(without repeating code)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

So I'm writing a simple React.js app and just have a question about setting state, can this be done any cleaner?

```
const enemy = this.state.enemy;
        if (this.state.isRock) {
            enemy === "rock"
                ? this.setState({ result: "Draw!" })
                : enemy === "paper"
                ? this.setState({ result: "You lose!" })
                : enemy === "scissors"
                ? this.setState({ result: "You win!" })
                : this.setState({ result: null });
        } else if (this.state.isPaper) {
            enemy === "rock"
                ? this.setState({ result: "You win!" })
                : enemy === "paper"
                ? this.setState({ result: "Draw!" })
                : enemy === "scissors"
                ? this.setState({ result: "You lose!" })
                : this.setState({ result: null });
        } else if (this.state.isScissors) {
            enemy === "rock"
                ? this.setState({ result: "You lose!" })
                : enemy === "paper"
                ? this.setState({ result: "You win!" })
                : enemy === "scissors"
                ? this.setState({ result: "Draw!" })
                : this.setState({ result: null });
        }
```

Comment: Look into using a switch statement...

Answer (score 4):

Considering there are only three possible states (win, lose, draw), we only need to check for two of them.  Draw is easy to check for, so we only need the state of win or lose.  Here is an example:

```
const enemy = this.state.enemy;
let wins = {
    "rock"     : "scissors",
    "paper"    : "rock" ,
    "scissors" : "paper",
}
let play = (this.state.isRock ? "rock" : (
  this.state.isPaper ? "paper" : (
    this.state.isScissors ? "scissors" : null
    )
  )
)

if (!wins[play]) {
    this.setState({ result: null })
} else if (enemy == play) {
    this.setState({ result: "Draw!" })
} else if (wins[play] == enemy) {
    this.setState({ result: "You win!" })
} else {
    this.setState({ result: "You lose!" })
}
```

Comment: Yes, and it could even be way simpler by saving player's state as string rather than these isXXX booleans: https://jsfiddle.net/5tfyqj6k/

Answer (score 3):

You can have the conditions as part of the map as the condition never changes and set the state.

```js
const condition = {
  "rock": {
    "paper": "You lose!",
    "sccissors": "You win!",
    "rock": "Draw!"
  },
  "paper": {
    "rock": "You win!",
    "sccissors": "You lose!",
    "paper": "Draw!"
  },
  "sccissors": {
    "rock": "You lose!",
    "paper": "You win!",
    "sccissors": "Draw!"
  }
};

function getResult(enemy, isRock, isScissors, isPaper) {
  let result = null;
  
  if (isRock) {
    result = condition['rock'][enemy];
  } else if (isPaper) {
    result = condition['paper'][enemy];
  } else if (isScissors) {
    result = condition['scissors'][enemy];
  }
  
  return result;
}

const {
  isRock, 
  isScissors,
  isPaper,
  enemy
} = this.state;


this.setState({
  result: getResult(enemy, isRock, isScissors, isPaper)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an interesting approach you can try that uses a for in loop and only one if statement.

You could use object literals to set the values of what each state is:

```
const stateConditions = {
    "isRock": {
      "paper": "You lose!",
      "scissors": "You win!",
      "rock": "Draw!"
    },
    "isPaper": {
      "rock": "You win!",
      "scissors": "You lose!",
      "paper": "Draw!"
    },
    "isScissors": {
      "rock": "You lose!",
      "paper": "You win!",
      "scissors": "Draw!"
    }
  };
```

In the above object if you did state = stateConditions['isRock'] then you would get the corresponding conditions for rock

With javascript this.state['isRock'] is the same as this.state.isRock. And you can use a property to loop over each property in an object using [forin](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp), thus you can do the following to find the current state. This way you can loop through all of the possible states and see if this.state['somestate'] is true:

```
for (let state in stateConditions) {
    if (this.state[state] === true) {
        // you found which state was true!
    }
}
```

Final code:

```
const conditions = {
    "isRock": {
      "paper": "You lose!",
      "scissors": "You win!",
      "rock": "Draw!"
    },
    "isPaper": {
      "rock": "You win!",
      "scissors": "You lose!",
      "paper": "Draw!"
    },
    "isScissors": {
      "rock": "You lose!",
      "paper": "You win!",
      "scissors": "Draw!"
    }
  };

  for (const state in conditions) {
      // check if this is the state
      if (this.state[state]) {
          this.setState({ result: condition[state][this.state.enemy] });
          break;
      }
  }
```

Here is an interesting article on [replacing switch statements with object literals](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a different spin on one of the current answers, to reduce repetition:

```
const condition = {
  rock: {
    paper: -1,
    scissors: 1,
    rock: 0
  },
  paper: {
    paper: 0,
    scissors: -1,
    rock: 1
  },
  scissors: {
    paper: 1,
    scissors: 0,
    rock: -1
  }
};

function getResult({enemy, isRock, isScissors, isPaper}) {
  let result = null;

  if (isRock) {
    result = condition.rock[enemy];
  } else if (isPaper) {
    result = condition.paper[enemy];
  } else if (isScissors) {
    result = condition.scissors[enemy];
  }

  return result === -1 ? "You loose!" : result === 1 ? "You win!" : result === 0 ? "Draw!" : null;
}

this.setState({
  result: getResult(this.state)
});
```